# React bad Header Request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build new Header Request by looping inside the API and getting specific data. What I'm trying to achieve is to get some specific data and to put in Request Payload. But the result that I'm achieving with my code seems to be wrong.

API looks like:

```
id: 12345
profileID: 3456
name: "Profile Name"
details: [
    0: {
        detailID: 4556
        progressID: 5678
        comment:
            0: {
                id: 63434
                commentNumber: 34
                image: 'image.jpg'
            }
    }
]
documents:
    0: {
        id: 3567
        docId: 6753
        docName: 'doc.pdf'
    }
```

and what I need to achieve is:

```
id: 12345
details: [
    0: {
        detailId: {
            0: 3567
        }
        document: {
            0: 3567
        }

    }
]
```

So, tried to move inside api:

```
        .then((response) => {
        const getID: Object.values(response).map(result => result.details.map(test => test.detailID));
        const getComm = Object.values(response).map(result => result.details.map(test => test.comment.map(
              cId => cId.id
            )));
         const getDoc = Object.values(response).map(result => result.documents.map(test => test.id));
         setProfile({
            id: getID,
            details: {
                getComm, getDoc
            }
         })
    });
```

and I'm achieving the result like that:

```
id: {
    0: {
        0: 12345
    }
```

Comment: Example is unclear and does not match the code you have written, you need to give a more thorough example. Why is the detailID and documentId same in the answer that you are trying to achieve? What if there are multiple comments in a detail object inside the details array, or multiple elements in documents array but only 1 in details array. Please clarify with a proper example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have used  Object.values, instead try with  Object.keys and proceed further